# Why does an optical pyrometer read low in the open?

Tags: temperature, thermal-radiation

An optical pyrometer relies on the fact that the brightness of heat radiation from a body depends on its temperature. I have come across the fact that an optical pyrometer invariably reads low when used in the open - but not so when used for an incandescent object (such as a red hot iron piece) in a furnace, where it will give the correct reading of the temperature. I found this, for instance, [here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=kIYJAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA337&lpg=PA337&dq=optical+pyrometer+reads+low+in+open&source=bl&ots=KtfWSac4P1&sig=tTUaDY6zekT1fXb-S5cuSpg64NI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjU4pf02NrJAhXBwI4KHe0DD64Q6AEIKjAC#v=onepage&q=optical%20pyrometer%20reads%20low%20in%20open&f=false) and [here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Qnt9AwAAQBAJ&pg=PR186&dq=an+optical+pyrometer+reads+low+in+open&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjPqcW52trJAhVDHo4KHXiEDC8Q6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=an%20optical%20pyrometer%20reads%20low%20in%20open&f=false). I have not found any reason for the fact, expect that the error in reading in the open is lower for bodies with high emissivity - and a hint that it might have something to do with reflection of light.

Is it that the light reflected by the incandescent object in the open also appears to be directed from it and is received by the pyrometer, *along* with the light the object radiates? Although this suggests a positive deviation; the body should appear brighter and its temperature *higher*. Moreover, reflection of light will even take place in a furnace - so this does not seem to be the right reason.

Comment: Please provide a citation for your claim.  You might also want to look up the wavelength operating range of your pyrometer -- good chance it ignores everything with wavelength shorter than 625nm, for example, which would explain a lot of the reason for your situation.

Comment: I think that you need to be more precise in your description. What do you mean that your pyrometer reads low "when used in the open"? Give a specific example. For instance, do you mean that it reads low even when used on an outdoor grill?

Comment: I am not speaking of my own experience in this question - this is a fact I came across in books.